# CSS button size in chrome different to safari (both webkit browsers though?)

Tags: css, google-chrome, webkit

I have a base css which amongst other elements, sets my inputs to:

```
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  border:0;
  font-size:100%;
  font:inherit;
  vertical-align:baseline;
```

And i also have this for the specific button in question

```
header input[type=submit] { background:#383838; color:#FFF; padding:4px 5px; }
```

Everything is fine except the input button in Chrome which is 2 pixels shorter in height and in width then every other browser (so like there is 1 pixel diff for each side). What makes this more frustrating is this isnt affecting safari which is a webkit browser also.

Any ideas why?

Cheers,
Adi.

Comment: Sorry, will do re: acceptance. Image here (same styles for both) http://postimage.org/image/2vye375b8/

Comment: I dont really want to use js to browser sniff and adjust. Great to sort css alone (cant use line-height 'cos of FF bug)

Comment: Can you reproduce it on [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) or [JS Bin](http://jsbin.com/)? Also, what operating system are you using?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/5kLEf/ (if you view on chrome and safari you can see size diff) I am on Windows 7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`button`s and `input`s are rendered (slightly) differently by every browser (padding, margins, etc.) If you want the exact same result across every browser, you'll need to target each specifically with different style rules.

Comment: Thats what I had worried. Ta for the input.

Answer (score 0):

you should try CSS reset at the first of the style-sheet document. some browser take their default styling .. so this may also be an issue